# How To Invoke Anonymous Function in Another Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I have a JS code like this which I have assigned an anonymous function to `photos` variable in `map.on("load", function() {}` now it seems the `photos` is never invoking! as even I tried to do a simple `console.log("Is This working")` it is not loading the log!

```
 var photos;
 map.on("load", function() {
   domStyle.set(query("a.action.zoomTo")[0], "display", "none");
   photos = function(){
     for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
       var point = new Point(projects[i].Longitude, projects[i].Latitude);
       var pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(); 
       pointSymbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE);
       pointSymbol.setSize(9);
       var pointInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(); 
       pointInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
       pointInfoTemplate.setContent('   ');
       var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol).setInfoTemplate(pointInfoTemplate);
       points.push(pointGraphic);
     }
     for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
       map.graphics.add(points[i]);
     }
     console.log(points);
   };
   photos.then(addClusters, error);
 });
```

Can you please let me know why this is not working?

Thanks

> Update:

```
  map.on("load", function() {
  domStyle.set(query("a.action.zoomTo")[0], "display", "none");
  photos = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {

    var point = new Point(projects[i].Longitude, projects[i].Latitude);
    var pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(); 
    pointSymbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE);
    pointSymbol.setSize(9);
    var pointInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(); 
    pointInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
    pointInfoTemplate.setContent('   ');
    var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol).setInfoTemplate(pointInfoTemplate);
    points.push(pointGraphic);
}
for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    map.graphics.add(points[i]);
}
console.log(points);
};
    photos().then(addClusters, error);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never invoking the `photos` function. Be sure to include the parenthesis after the variable name to make it execute, like `photos()`. Also the photos function doesn't return anything so the `.then()` will fail.

Comment: Thanks for comment fadich, but I am kinda confused here! Di I have to declare  the `photos` like `var photos();` Can you please let me know where should I exactly do this?

Comment: Your declaration is correct. The issue is on the second to last line where you attempt to use the function. The () tell JS to execute the function. Since you left those off it won't do anything. It should be  photos().then(addClusters, error); (although as I mentioned the .then() will fail because photos doesn't return anything)

Comment: It is not a promise, that is why I'm saying it won't work. photos would need to return a promise for it to work.

Comment: @jfadich, can you please take a look at update? I did what you said but still nothing ! No error message but not even console log?1

Comment: @Snarf, I am trying to use a function like https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html from ArcGIS map, I am not sure if `then` is a promise or not?~

Comment: Here is the whole idea https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html

Comment: As you can see ArcGIS API is using `esriRequest()` to read JSON data from URL, in my case I am not strong data on the server in a file and everything is doable on fly from Ajax request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88236/discussion-between-suffii-and-snarf).